# Como poner o habilitar boton de atras en toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar

me esta pasando algo muy raro, no me sale el botón para ir atrás en la toolbar y en un proyecto anterior si me sale.. seguí los mismo pasos con la diferencia que ahora la toolbar la tengo en un xml aparte pero no sé por que no me sale nada x.x

este es toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
  android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
  android:elevation="4dp"
  android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
  app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

mi MainActivity tiene un recyclerView, cuando presiono un item voy a mi segunda actividad en que quiero que salga el botón atrás pero no me resulta x.x

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/RelativeLayoutMain"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context="com.example.pauli.applista.MainActivity">

  <include android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      layout="@layout/toolbar" />

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/reciclador"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:padding="3dp"
      android:scrollbars="vertical"
      android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

En el manifest tengo asignada la ctivida principal como padre de la segunda

```
<activity
        android:name=".Segunda"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
</activity>
```

En el tema de la aplicación tengo el código para habilitar mi toolbar

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- habilitar toolbar -->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Ahora en mi MainActivity.java asigno la toolbar para que aparezca

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Sigo con todo el codigo para inicializar recycler y todo eso.. en el metodo para el click de cada item en el recyclerView inicio la segunda actividad.

```
@Override
public void onClick(ImagenAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int idImagen) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Segunda.class);
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt("IMAGEN", idImagen);
    intent.putExtras(b);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

En el xml de mi segunda actividad de momento solo incluyo la toolbar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/activity_segunda"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context="com.example.pauli.applista.Segunda">

<include android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Y mi archivo Segunda.java solo tiene el onCreate

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_segunda);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
}
```

Según yo esto está bien y debería funcionar pero no sé por que no quiere salir el botón.. espero que alguien sepa.. quizás es algo muy tonto que estoy haciendo mal x.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asegura que tu clase `Activity` extienda de 
[AppCompactActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html), con esto puedes realizar el cargado del ToolBar:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
}
```

Encontre como realizarlo lo puedes ver en la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html)

Para habilitar la navegación se realiza mediante el llamado de `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

Si `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()` se establece como `true` si la selección de "home" regresa a un solo nivel en la UI en lugar de volver al nivel superior o primera página.

Comment: Si, todas extienden de AppCompactActivity

Comment: En que sistema operativo pruebas?

Comment: Estoy usando android studio en un windows 10 y pruebo la aplicación en mi celular versión de android 5.0... no se por que no funciona... la aplicación anterior que hice si se ve x.x

Answer (score 0):

Ya me funciono solo tenia que escribir

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

en vez de lo que estaba poniendo al principio... pero ahora me gustaria saber cual es la diferencia con

```
getSupportActionBar().setDefaultDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

o encontre otras más y ahi me puse a probar cual servia

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```